# Huggingface: Optimal way to tokenize a single string?

Tags: huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

Let’s say my training dataset is just one long string. What is the correct way to tokenize this?

I have this so far:

```
trainenc = tokenizer(train_dataset['text'], return_tensors='pt', max_length=128, truncation=True, padding=True, return_overflowing_tokens=True)
```

What arguments should i keep?

How do I split up my long list of tokens into batches where each element of the batch is short enough to fit inside the model?